# Binding to a view model with a nested list of type class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to bind to a view model for a POST request into my controller action, and it appears the correct parameters are being sent, but my viewmodels data seems to be `null` despite trying multiple things.  I have the following view model that I'm binding to from within my view:

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel {
   public List < OrderDetail > OrderDetails;
}
```

The data loads into my views properly, here's what the main view looks like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="update-orderdetail" action="/orderdetail/update" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover results">
            <thead>
                ... tr tags ...
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.OrderDetails)
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here's what my `EditorTemplates/OrderDetail.cshtml` looks like:

```
@model CorinthVendorPortal.Models.OrderDetail
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PurchaseOrder)</td>
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PurchaseOrder)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { @type = "number", @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.StockCode)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MStockDes)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.OrderQtyOrig)</td>
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.OrderQtyCur, new { @type = "number", @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.DueDateOrig)</td>
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DueDateCur, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ShipDateOrig)</td>
    <td class="editable">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ShipDateCur, new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what the `OrderDetail` controller's `Update` method looks like (in which my model's `OrderDetails` property is `null`):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Update(OrderDetailViewModel model) {
    var l = model; // model.OrderDetails is always null
    ....
    return null;
}
```

Here are the parameters that are being POSTed:

```
OrderDetails[0].ID:1
OrderDetails[0].PurchaseOrder:0246298
OrderDetails[0].Price:8.85000
OrderDetails[0].OrderQtyCur:200.000000
OrderDetails[0].DueDateCur:
OrderDetails[0].ShipDateCur:
OrderDetails[1].ID:2
OrderDetails[1].PurchaseOrder:0246298
OrderDetails[1].Price:1.40000
OrderDetails[1].OrderQtyCur:750.000000
OrderDetails[1].DueDateCur:
OrderDetails[1].ShipDateCur:
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using field in your view model, but MVC binding works only with properties.

Change

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel {
   public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails;
}
```

to

```
public class OrderDetailViewModel {
   public List <OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}
```

and your code should start working.

Comment: I was so sure that the issue was in my view somewhere that I completely overlooked the property itself in the view model...  How frustrating!  Thanks for the help :D